# Differentiable at a point definition.

Tags: derivatives

Let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $a\in A.$ 
We say that, when $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ exists, then the  function $f$ differentiable at $a \in A$. So, does the point $a \in A$ is a limit point of $A$ or is interior point of $A$?

Comment: When you are in $\Bbb R$ you can take $a$ to be _any_ point in $A$ (notice $f(a)$ appears in the definition)

Comment: The definition just requires $a \in A$. That's it.

Comment: @WillM. let $f(x) =x, D_f =[1,2]$ function$ f $ differentiable at $1$or $2$?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no assumptions on the domain $A$?

Comment: Actually you need that $a$ is in the closure of $A\setminus\{a\}$. Otherwise the limit is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

If the point $a $ is not in the interior of $A $, we speak about differentiability on the left $...,a] $ or on the right $[a,.. $.

Comment: let $f(x)=x , D_f =\mathbb{R} - \{\frac{1}{n} : n\in  \mathbb{Z}\} $ function $f$ differentiable $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

In a typical calculus textbook you will note that many authors would put it as a requirement that $A$ is an open set (that is, every point of $A$ is an interior point of $A$). This is because $a$ being interior to $A$ allows us to take both left and right limits at $a$. So you may take it as something out of which an author tries not to confuse the reader and at the same time probably not to get ahead of himself, which is just like an elementary-school teacher usually "lets" his students think that division only applies to positive integers.

But there is no further "technical" reason to stop at requiring $A$ open. If $A := [1, 2[$, a half-open interval, for instance, then we still can define the derivative of $f$ at $1$ by taking merely the right limit (there is no left limit to take in this case) of the difference quotient about $f$ at $1$.